# Understanding encoding of extracted features

Tags: matlab, image-processing, encoding, classification, feature-detection

The encoding I am focusing on is fisher encoding as i has shown to have best results with my work. So I want to test fisher encoding on my extracted (SIFT) features and test the performance of the system with or without encoding.

Rather than starting fresh I found that vl_feat has a built in library for fisher encoding and they have a tutorial for that as well linked [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/encodings.html)

Now I have already done most of what is required but what actually does get encoded is confusing me, for example the tutorial makes it clear that fisher encoding is performed using the parameters obtained by GMM such as `[means, covariances, priors]` and the SIFT extracted features are to be used here in GMM as per the tutorial:

> The Fisher encoding uses GMM to construct a visual word dictionary. To
>   exemplify constructing a GMM, consider a number of 2 dimensional data
>   points. In practice, these points would be a collection of SIFT or
>   other local image features.

```
numFeatures = 5000 ;
dimension = 2 ;
data = rand(dimension,numFeatures) ;

numClusters = 30 ;
[means, covariances, priors] = vl_gmm(data, numClusters);
```

Then once I have performed this step I am to encode another data set? This is what confuses me. I have already used my extracted SIFT features in generating the parameters for GMM.

> Next, we create another random set of vectors, which should be encoded
>   using the Fisher Vector representation and the GMM just obtained:

```
encoding = vl_fisher(datatoBeEncoded, means, covariances, priors);
```

So here `encoded` is the final result but WHAT has it encoded? I want my SIFT features that I extracted from my images to be encoded, but if I follow the tutorial that is used in GMM. If that is the case then what is `datatoBeEncoded`? Am I to use the SIFT feats here again?

Thank you

**Update**:

@Shai

Thank you but I believe I must be doing something wrong. I dont quite understand what you mean by "compare images to themselves". I have 4 classes, from each class 1000 images. So I used the first 600 images from class 1 to learn the gmm parameters and then use these parameters to encode the fisher vectors

```
numClusters = 128 ;
[means, covariances, priors] = vl_gmm(data, numClusters);
```

So each `means, covariances` are of the size `128 x 128` and priors of the size `1 x 128`

Now when I use these to encode the fisher vector on the 400 images using the function

```
encoding = vl_fisher(datatoBeEncoded, means, covariances, priors);
```

the size of the encoding is very different, something along the size of `12000 x 1`. These cannot be compared to the models generated.

I already had a system that was working on the non-encoded version of the dataset and it was working well, but i wanted to see how encoding will make a difference, theoretically the results should be improved.

I can add the code here if needed, but it is for UBM- GMM and the reason I am confused is because the training method you mentioned is what I am using for UBM.

If I just encode the test images I cannot use them in the classifier because of the size mismatch.

Maybe I am not picking this correctly or making some silly mistake, would it be possible to get a simple example through which I can understand the working.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You have two phases in the process:
(1) *training* where you use learn some statistical properties of your domain, and
(2) *testing* where you use the learned representation/models and apply them to new samples.

Accordingly, you should split your dataset of features into two "splits" one for learning the GMMs for the Fisher encoding (a *training* set) , and another split to apply the encoding to (a *test* set).

Usually you sample a significant amount of images that well represent your domain of interest (for example, if you are interested in people you should consider many pictures of people indoor and outdoor, closeups and group photos etc.) You extract as many SIFT descriptors as you can from these training images and use them to learn the model:

```
numClusters = 30 ;
[means, covariances, priors] = vl_gmm(TrainingData, numClusters);
```

Once you have this model *save it*, then you can apply it to **new** photos to encode them

```
encoding = vl_fisher(TestData, means, covariances, priors);
```

Note that while `TrainingData` is in general very large and may be collected from dozens (or even hundreds) of images, `TestData` may be significantly smaller, and even be descriptors collected from a *single* image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if I have 1000 images, and use 600 for Training and the rest for testing then how do I compare the two? I mean, in this case, the training will be in terms of the ``gmm`` parameters whereas the test will be in terms of ``fisher vectors``, using a classifier how will they compare? Won't that be like comparing one feature type (training) against another feature type(test)? Sorry maybe I am not understanding your explanation properly, if possible can you please provide an example of how this would work? Many thanks

Comment: @FarazKhan you are not suppose to compare againt the training set - that would be "cheating". You may use 600 photos for learning the model and then compare the fisher vectors of the 400 images to themselves: finding similar images etc. For instance, you can pick one image (out of the 400) and search for the 10 images with the closest vector - that is finding the 10 most similar images.

Comment: there was too much to write here so I updated my original question, Can you please have a look at it. Many thanks

Comment: what is the size of `dataToBeEncoded`? I find it hard to understand why `encoding` is 1200-by-1 vector, when your `numClusters` is 128...

Comment: The size of the ``datatobeEncoded`` is the same as ``data``. Like you suggested I divided my database in two parts one for training and one for testing. they are ``rootSIFT`` features. Each image is presented by features of size ``128 x 1``. I have 128 clusters so the ``means`` is of size ``128 x 128``. But when I give this data to ``vl_fisher`` I get the ``12000 x 1`` vector. Most of the elements in this vector are zero with some elements which hold actual value

Comment: @FarazKhan (1) how many SIFT descriptors do you extract from each image? (2) how many descriptors are in `data` and how many in `datatoBeEncoded`? (3) what is the exact `size` of these two arrays (#columns, #rows)? (4) I do not have experience with `vl_fisher` but from what I read in the manual, the encoding size should be `numOfClusters` by dimension of descriptor - I can't see how 1-by-12,000 fits that description...